# How to add a new JSON array field to existing MySQL JSON array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have a MySQL (v5.7) database that has a table called `deals` which contains a JSON column called `jdeal_status`.

This column contains data in the following format:

```
{
   "trackIssues":[
      {
         "date":[
            "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00"
         ],
         "notes":[
            {
               "date":"2020-01-28T12:30:46-05:00",
               "name":"Joe Robbs",
               "note":"New note"
            },
            {
               "date":"2020-01-28T17:45:29-05:00",
               "name":"John Ha",
               "note":"New attachment"
            }
         ],
         "value":3000,
         "isResolved":false,
         "issueIndex":0
      },
      { ...other array objects },
   ]
 }
```

I would like to add a new array field called `attachments` to the `trackIssues` array (at trackIssues[0]) if it doesn't exist or append to it if it does exist. However, I am stuck on just adding the new field to the existing array.

I have tried doing the following:

```
UPDATE deals set jdeal_status = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(jdeal_status, '$.trackIssues[0]', 
JSON_OBJECT(
    'attachments', 
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'date', "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00",
      'file', 'yyyy.pdf'
    ) 
))  WHERE id = 2;"
```

but it appends to the trackIssues array and not element at [0] as follows:

```
{
   "trackIssues":[
      [
         {
            "date":[
               "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00"
            ],
            "notes":[
               {
                  "date":"2020-01-28T12:30:46-05:00",
                  "name":"Joe Robbs",
                  "note":"New note"
               },
               {
                  "date":"2020-01-28T17:45:29-05:00",
                  "name":"John Ha",
                  "note":"New attachment"
               }
            ],
            "value":3000,
            "isResolved":false,
            "issueIndex":0
         },
         {
            "attachments":{
               "date":"2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00",
               "file":"yyyy.pdf"
            }
         }
      ]
   ]
 }
```

Whereas I want this:

```
   "trackIssues":[
      {
         "date":[
            "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00"
         ],
         "notes":[
            {
               "date":"2020-01-28T12:30:46-05:00",
               "name":"Joe Robbs",
               "note":"New note"
            },
            {
               "date":"2020-01-28T17:45:29-05:00",
               "name":"John Ha",
               "note":"New attachment"
            }
         ],
         "value":3000,
         "isResolved":false,
         "issueIndex":0,
         "attachments":[
            {
               "date":"2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00",
               "file":"yyyy.pdf"
            }           
         ]       
      }
   ]
 }
```

I am not sure why this doesn't work as I am not sure how else to specify the first element of the `trackIssues` array (`$.trackIssues[0]`). I have tried other ways of doing this (`JSON_SET`) but can't seem to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated including how to create if it doesn't exist or append if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

To append to the array when it already exists, or insert when it doesn't exist, you need to use `JSON_CONTAINS_PATH` to determine if the array already exists, and, dependent on that, either `JSON_INSERT` an array as described below, or add to the array using `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND`. The full query:

```
UPDATE deals
SET jdeal_status = CASE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(jdeal_status, 'one', '$.trackIssues[0].attachments')
  WHEN 0 THEN JSON_INSERT(jdeal_status, '$.trackIssues[0].attachments', 
    JSON_ARRAY(
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'date', "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00",
        'file', 'yyyy.pdf'
      )
    )
  )
  ELSE JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(jdeal_status, '$.trackIssues[0].attachments',
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'date', "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00",
      'file', 'yyyy.pdf'
    )
  )
  END
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2700895b33795275780b3def00d9ee2d)

**Original answer**

What you need to do is `JSON_INSERT` the `attachments` array of objects into `$trackIssues[0]`:

```
UPDATE deals set jdeal_status = JSON_INSERT(jdeal_status, '$.trackIssues[0].attachments', 
    JSON_ARRAY(
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'date', "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00",
        'file', 'yyyy.pdf'
      )
    ) 
)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c121a67347c2b82d16a9a8149da1326c)

Output from pretty-printing the JSON:

```
{
    "trackIssues": [
        {
            "date": [
                "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00"
            ],
            "notes": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-01-28T12:30:46-05:00",
                    "name": "Joe Robbs",
                    "note": "New note"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-01-28T17:45:29-05:00",
                    "name": "John Ha",
                    "note": "New attachment"
                }
            ],
            "value": 3000,
            "isResolved": false,
            "issueIndex": 0,
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-01-28T12:04:42-05:00",
                    "file": "yyyy.pdf"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```